# Unable to email with sendPasswordResetEmail method in Firebase and android project

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create an authentication system in Android with Firebase Authentication, everything works, but email to reset password that is never send.

```
 private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

 btResetContrasena.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                email = etEmailResetPassword.getText().toString();
                if (!email.isEmpty()) {
                    mDialog.setMessage("Espera un momento");
                    mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                    mDialog.show();
                    resetPassword(email);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(cambiarContrasenaLogin_Activity.this,"Debe Ingresar el email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                mDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

    }



  private void resetPassword(String email) {

      String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        if (language.equals("en") || (language.equals("es"))) {
            mAuth.setLanguageCode(language);
        } else {
            mAuth.setLanguageCode("en");
        }
        mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    Toast.makeText(cambiarContrasenaLogin_Activity.this,"Se ha enviado un correo un correo para reestablecer la contraseña",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(cambiarContrasenaLogin_Activity.this,login_Activity.class));

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(cambiarContrasenaLogin_Activity.this,"No se pudo enviar correo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });


    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the email wasn't sent? Or did you not receive it? If the latter, did you check your spam folder?

Comment: Hi Frank, You were right I had lots of emails in my spam folder. Thank you to remember me that I have a that folder !!!!!!